# How to stop url request to validate credit card number

Tags: php, laravel, security

I have a website (PHP Laravel site) that uses Brainstree to process credit card payments.  Today the site receives A LOT direct request to 1 url that passes in credit card information.  It seems the hacker figures out our parameters and is using my site trying to validate their stolen credit card numbers.

Here is an example of a request.

http://mysite/renew?card_nubmer=42693111111111&ccv=014&expiration_month=11&expiration_year=2019&first_name=beqnykit&last_name=fozwgfrpn&postal_code=44101&type=visa&price=12year=1&country_name=USA&currency=%24

It is causing the CPU usage to be 100%, slowing down my site.

Before our code was processing the request and display an error page. Now it validates the request and redirects invalid renew request to log in page.  The CPU load is still 100%.

What can I do to stop this or stop the CPU load, at the least?

Comment: Are the hits all coming from the same IP? If so, you can pretty easily just block it inbound.

Comment: Use POST variables and CSRF. Passing credit card credentials as GET is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Also, I hope that page is hosted on HTTPS and not HTTP else you've got a lot of 'splainin to do.

Comment: 1) I will check about the IP. 2) We have changed it to POST.  So this is not a problem any more.  We also checks for valid session/user before processing any request. 3) The site is using https.

Comment: Do you have any kind of firewall? Like ufw maybe? And perhaps using something like recaptcha to slow down the automatic attack? Application level throttling?

Comment: If those are real, actual credit card numbers you should probably take the extra step of *calling the police*.

Comment: @frz3993 It looks like a valid request.  How does a firewall help in this case?  recaptcha is not appropriate just to stop this; the request will keep on coming after the batch is over even with recaptcha.  We are checking for valid session before processing the quest through POST.  So the new request will be redirected to log in page.  It is the high CPU load that is the issue. IP blocking sounds like a good solution.

Comment: You can set the firewall rule to block traffic if lets say too many failed request then block connection from certain ip for some amount of times. Although firewall does require more processing power for more complex rules

Comment: Look into using CSRF tokens. It should help reduce a lot of the traffic.

Comment: As for the recaptcha I am assuming they can register as user and automate the request so I suggested that

Comment: please tell me you are not sending credit card information via GET request

Comment: oh , you said you changed it. thank god

Comment: The IP blocking won't work, because they are changing the IPs.

Comment: Here is the update. The hacker really analyzes the site. It create free users.  Each free user uses a credit card to submit an order for a paid membership.  We are a target because the amount is small. Using POST doesn't fix this hack. So we have added account activation email and recaptcha in account creation and order page. Luckily, it is stopped pretty quickly. I am just putting the info here to share experience. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Enable the use of CSRF field, it's a must. You're saying you began handling the request as POST, so that's fine.

This route also has to be available for authenticated users only. Add a proper middleware if you haven't yet.

As for additional protection I would recommend to use some throttle middleware. Consider using this package or something similar. It will not allow to use the method more often than the number of times per minute you specify. https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Throttle

Answer (score 0):

Here is the update. The hacker really analyzes the site. It create free users. Each free user uses a credit card to submit an order for a paid membership. We are a target because the amount is small. Using POST doesn't fix this hack. So we have added account activation email and recaptcha in account creation and order page. Luckily, it is stopped pretty quickly. I am just putting the info here to share experience. Thanks for all the help!